# Merge lists with common column using lambdas and streams in java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have two scenarios with below two domain objects :

```
class A{
     String id;
      String name;
       String value;
      String val1;
      String val2;
 }

class PropVal{
String id;
String propVal1;
String propVal2;
String propVal3;
String propVal4;
 }
```

**1) I have 4 lists**

```
List<String> 1 = { id1,id2 ,id3}
List<String> 2 = { "one","two","three"}
```

Note- List 1 elements correspond to List 2 elements like id1 = "one" , id2 = "two" and so on

```
List<String> 3 =  { "one","two","three"}
List<String> 4 =  { 1,2,3}
```

Note- List 3 elements correspond to List 4 elements like  "one" = 1 , "two" = 2 and so on

All values of these list correspond to properties of class A so more lists like above with all properties so may be cannot make map of just two above lists.

What i want is to merge these lists based on common field,ie, name ( values is List 2 & list 3) like

```
List<A> onjList = {[id=id1,name=one,value=1] , [id=id2,name=two,value=2] ,[id=id3,name=three,value=3]..... }
```

**2) I have two lists**

```
List<A> onjList - {[id=id1,name=one,value=1] , [id=id2,name=two,value=2] ,[id=id3,name=three,value=3]..... } -----obtained from Step 1
List<PropVal> list 2 = { [id=id1,propVal1=w,propVal2=x,propVal3=y,propVal4=z] , [id=id2,propVal1=a,propVal2=b,propVal3=c,propVal4=d] ....}
```

I want a final list like

```
List<A> final List = {[id=id1,name=one,value=1,val1=w ,val2=x] , [id=id2,name= two,value = 2,val1 = a ,val2 = b]..... }
```

note val1 = propVal1 and val2 = propVal2.

What is the best way to do both of these scenarios ? Preferably using java 8 streams and lambdas ?

Comment: I've read the question 3 times, still can't make any sense out of it. Can you provide some clear input on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Eugene - Thanks for taking out the time. Not sure what you find confusing. Basically I am getting these different lists from different sources and ultimately need to merge these lists into single list of objects A.If you can point out the confusing part I will surely try to explain may in some other way

Answer (score 2):

Your examples are misleading. Numbers don’t make good variable names and all four lists are in the same order, but I assume, your question is supposed to imply that the first two list may have a different order than the other two, e.g.

```
List<String> aNames=Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
List<String> aIDs  =Arrays.asList("id1", "id2", "id3");

List<String> bNames =Arrays.asList("two", "one", "three");
List<String> bValues=Arrays.asList("2",   "1",   "3");
```

While merging all lists in one step is possible, the repeated linear search would yield an overall quadratic time complexity, so this is discouraged. Instead, merge two associated lists into a map, allowing efficient lookup, then, merge the other two with the map:

```
assert bNames.size()==bValues.size();
Map<String,String> bNameToValue = IntStream.range(0, bNames.size())
    .collect(HashMap::new, (m,i) -> m.put(bNames.get(i),bValues.get(i)), Map::putAll);

assert aNames.size()==aIDs.size();
List<A> list = IntStream.range(0, aNames.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> new A(aIDs.get(i), aNames.get(i), bNameToValue.get(aNames.get(i))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The considerations for the second task are similar. If the list of `PropVal` elements is not in the same order, i.e. a lookup is needed, it’s recommended to have a map, which implies that it might be simpler to let the previous step generate a map in the first place.

```
assert bNames.size()==bValues.size();
Map<String,String> bNameToValue = IntStream.range(0, bNames.size())
    .collect(HashMap::new, (m,i)->m.put(bNames.get(i),bValues.get(i)), Map::putAll);

assert aNames.size()==aIDs.size();
Map<String,A> idToA = IntStream.range(0, aNames.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> new A(aIDs.get(i), aNames.get(i), bNameToValue.get(aNames.get(i))))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getId, Function.identity()));

List<PropVal> list2 = …
```

then, if `A` is mutable:

```
list2.forEach(pVal -> {
    A a = idToA.get(pVal.id);
    a.setVal1(pVal.propVal1);
    a.setVal2(pVal.propVal2);
    a.setVal3(pVal.propVal3);
    a.setVal4(pVal.propVal4);
});

List<A> finalList = new ArrayList<>(idToA.values());
```

or if `A` is immutable:

```
List<A> finalList = list2.stream()
     .map(pVal -> {
        A a = idToA.get(pVal.id);
        return new A(pVal.id, a.getName(), a.getValue(),
            pVal.propVal1, pVal.propVal2, pVal.propVal3, pVal.propVal4);
        })
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(note that this includes only those `A` instances into the list, for which a `PropVal` exists).

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful and close to what i was looking for.For second case I used like below.Created a map field in domain to contain prop val as it decouples by code with these properties.idToA.forEach((k,v)->{
   list.stream()
     .filter(p -> p.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(k))
     .forEach(m -> v.getRetMap().put(m.getPropname(),m.getVal()) );
  
   });

Answer (score 0):

Please do not abuse java 8 features! You have data design drawbacks. Provide useful methods in your classes, migrate to suitable data structures. In your model it is easy to get inconsistent data.

Do not delegate all your problems to lambdas and streams.